# InfluxQL modulo operator on WHERE clause for timestamp `now()` function

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I want to query my records from today at `00.00` to `now()`. The problem is that I want to do this dynamically so I need to manipulate the timestamp using `now()` function.

Here is the query as an example.

```
SELECT SUM("something")
FROM "any_table_whatsoever"
WHERE time >= (now() - (now() % 86400) - (now() % 3600))
```

Here is the response.

```
error parsing query: found %, expected ) at line 3, char 29
```

It seems InfluxQL doesn't support modulo over timestamp.
I also think that's I might treat it wrongs.
For your information, I'm using InfluxQL on Grafana.

Are there any alternatives to achieve this?

EDIT: My Grafana panel must not relying on both `$timeFilter` and `$__interval`. I mean, like, displaying a stats "so far today". That wouldn't work if I relying on such variables since when we change the interval on Grafana, the query would affected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate it. Grafana has a predefined time range for that `Today so far`, which will calculate times for the query automatically:
[image: Grafana]

Comment: My panel must display the result as I stated above. That's means my query must not relying on Grafana's predefined time range

Comment: Then you should remove tag Grafana because you need pure InfluxDB solution.

Comment: Removed. Thank you for your answer anyway

Comment: `time >= (now() - (now() % 86400) - (now() % 3600))` seem to always resolve to a time frame which is somewhat close to the current time. What sort of time range  are you trying to achieve here? I think what @JanGaraj may work for you.

Comment: @SamuelToh I have edited my question. The point is I need a "dynamic" time range from `00:00` on that day until current time. Using Grafana's predefined time wouldn't do it since when I updated the interval, my query would affected.

EDIT: As an example, today `00:00` until current time I edited this comment `09:21`.

Comment: My understanding is Grafana's time range is dynamic. When you build a dashboard saying "last 24 hours" this pre-defined time do not stop there as is, it moves. Maybe I didn't understand your question.